# C# PDF Writing: Is there an API that uses the GDI+ naming conversion that creates PDFs?

Tags: c#, pdf, gdi+

I have several GDI+ functions/programs that are capable of producing vector graphics.  Is there an API that uses the GDI+ naming conversion that creates PDFs.  So instead of creating a bitmap/canvas (I forget which one) and calling DrawRectangle, I could create a PDF_Canvas or something and call the PDF DrawRectangle?

Comment: Which PDF library are you using? If your question as meant as 'DO you know any good PDF library then look at itext sharp @ http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/

Answer (score 0):

use

```
using iTextSharp;

using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```